# How can i rectify the verify Error while reading the contents from excel file using jxl.jar in android

Tags: android, excel

I have developed the application to show the list of details from database.. the data's are extracted from excel file and store into database. while reading the contents from excel, i'm getting error:  **java.lang.VerifyError: p41.android.consol.products.StartSectionActivity**

My Code is here:

public class StartSectionActivity extends Activity {

```
Context context=this;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.product);

    try {
        //int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("p41.android.consol.products:raw/products.xls", null, null);
        //File f = new File(context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId));
        File excel=new File("p41.android.consol.products:raw/products.xls");

        Workbook book=Workbook.getWorkbook(excel);
        Sheet sheet1=book.getSheet(0);
        Cell a1=sheet1.getCell(0, 0);
        Log.d("Cell Value!", a1.getContents());
        /*String files[]=getResources().getAssets().list(null);

        Log.d("files", files[0]);*/
        //InputStream stream=getResources().getAssets().open("PRODUCT_MASTER.xls");


    } catch (BiffException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}